# Asp.Net routing to action with parameters

Tags: asp.net, routes, action

I have a routing config file with a following routing settings

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Login",
     url: "Account/login/{username}/{password}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login"}
);
```

and I have a Login action in an Account Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
        // do some
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        //do some
    }
```

I just want to call first action, with parameters not the second

Can you help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first one is POST and second one is GET. So the HTTP verb which you use for calling will decide what gets called.